# Reset Camera Rotation on Mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, aframe

I want to have a button, that sets the camera rotation to to the start point. 
For example: the scene starts and the user sees a blue circle. He moves the phone around and looks behind him. Now he wants to set this as new look direction, so that he looks at the blue circle again.

On desktop you can simply do that with an animation (set rotation of the camera).

But how is that possible on mobile?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`look-controls` will likely overwrite what you set directly on camera as rotation So:

1. Have a wrapper `<a-entity>` around the camera and set its rotation.
2. Pause the camera to pause look-controls `document.querySelector('[camera]').pause();` and then set rotation directly.